# c++ allocating and deallocating dynamical array of objects

Tags: c++

I'm a little bit confused on how to correctly allocate/deallocate dynamical array of objects. Here is my scenario:

```
class Tuple {

    public:

        Tuple(int columns);
        ~Tuple();

        void set(int i, string d);
        string get(int i);
        int columnCount();

    private:

        string *data;
        int columns;

};


Tuple::Tuple(int columns) {

    this->columns = columns > 0 ? columns : 0;
    if (this->columns  > 0) {
        data = new string[this->columns];
    } else {
        data = 0;
    }

}

Tuple::~Tuple() {
    if (columns > 0) {
        delete data; 
    }
}
```

Now, when I call the following code I get a segfault:

```
Tuple *t = new Tuple(4);
//some code
delete t;
```

What is wrong with my denstructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with my denstructor?

You wrote `delete` instead of `delete[]`.

BTW you're also missing a copy constructor and assignment operator, so your class is more subtly broken and rather susceptible to memory leaks.

> how to correctly allocate/deallocate dynamical array of objects.

Don't.

Use a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @the_candyman: Why use a vector? So that its allocation and de-allocation is managed for you and you don't need to worry about _any_ of this (including the three bugs in your attempt). In case you were wondering, there is no downside.

Comment: ok, but what if I want to allocate exactly a certain amount of memory?

Comment: @the_candyman: Then ask the vector to do that. Read the chapter about vectors in your C++ book. They're really easy to use: _way_ easier than this manual memory management gubbins.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use array delete operator in your destructor:

```
delete [] data;
```

The destructor can be written as

```
Tuple::~Tuple() {

    delete [] data; 
}
```

Comment: @Dan do not judge and you won't be judged

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - there are reproducible facts and there are false confidence and baseless speculations

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to look up the difference between:

delete
delete (nothrow_t)
delete []
delete [] (nothrow_t)

and look into their new equivalents,
and when one should be used over the other.